# How to say that an article is published (in a newspaper, blog, etc)

Tags: grammar, word-choice

When looking online in dictionaries, I can't figure out what word to use to say the following:

An article I wrote has been published in a newspaper.

> 私が書いた記事が新聞で**掲載**してくれていた。
>
> 私が書いた記事が新聞で**発刊**してくれていた。
>
> 私が書いた記事が新聞で**著して**くれていた。

Are any/all of these correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

発刊 is "to publish (an entire issue)". 著す is a (relatively uncommon) literary verb that means "to author/write (a book)." 掲載 is a reasonable word choice, but 掲載する is *transitive*.

After fixing the transitivity, we get:

> 私が書いた記事**を**新聞で掲載してくれていた。
>   (I noticed) (someone) had kindly published an article I wrote.

While this is now grammatical, this is a fairly nuanced sentence. For one, ～てくれる is probably not necessary unless you really have a reason to say it. For one, ～ていた means you just noticed the article had been already out for a while.

A natural way to say "～ is now published" is actually much simpler:

> 私が書いた記事が新聞で掲載された。 (or 掲載されました)